# Scroll Wheel in Delphi 7 with CodeRush

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, coderush, scrollwheel

One casualty of my brief dalliance with Delphi 2010 and subsequent return to using Delphi 7 was my acceptance of the wheel-scrolling behaviour in Delphi 7 with CodeRush installed.

The scroll wheel scrolls horizontally in that environment, which I've accepted for all these many years. But it sure was nice to have vertical scrolling while in D2010. Now, I wonder if there is any 'fix' to achieve the 'natural' scroll direction in my environment. Any old CodeRush/D7 users out there with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I work on a development team that uses Delphi 7 and CodeRush and to my knowledge none of us have experienced this problem. I am currently on Windows 7, but I've used D7 and CodeRush on XP and Vista also. I've also used two different machines in that time frame.

Are you sure the combination of software is causing the problem? If you uninstall CodeRush are you able to scroll vertically? Is it possible the problem is hardware related, i.e. some sort of weird driver issue?

I'm on Delphi 7.0 Build 8.1 and CodeRush 7.04d Professional.

Comment: LDB, sorry about not responding earlier. I completely forgot I added this question. I've been busy with a network overhaul and haven't programmed a line of code in almost a month. That said, I am going to jump back into it in the next two weeks and will do some testing on non-combinatorial software situations. Thanks for giving me a little hope. GM